# Dismissing splash screen using Robotium

Tags: android, splash-screen, robotium

I am using Robotium to automate Android UI. The app I am testing has a splash screen when it is launched and the screen is shown for x seconds. On tapping the screen before x seconds, the splash screen has to be dismissed.

I have tried `solo.clickOnScreen(100, 100)` , `solo.sendKey(66)` , where 66 corresponds to RETURN key. But the splash screen is not dismissed.

How do I simulate the user's action of tapping the screen to dismiss the splash screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify a view in the splashscreen and then click on it.
Something like:
View v = solo.getView(R.id.something)
solo.clickOnView(v)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as

```
Activity activity = solo.getCurrentActivity();
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus(); 
solo.clickOnView(view);
```